# Превратить псевдо-элемент в подложку. Как быть с z-index?

Tags: z-index, html, css

Требуется сделать подложку элементу - слой, который выглядывает из под этого элемента на пару пикселей. В обычном порядке это div в div и внешнему пару пикселей padding`а.

Хочется сделать без дополнительной обертки, псевдоклассом li:

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello z-index</li>
</ul>​
```

[Набросок](http://jsfiddle.net/YGVkG/). Псевдо-элемент пока скрыт.

1. [Пробуем](http://jsfiddle.net/YGVkG/1/). Псевдо-элемент перекрывает наш. Ну это ожидаемо.
2. [Пробуем](http://jsfiddle.net/YGVkG/2/) загнать псевдо-элемент под li добавлением отрицательного z-index. Ожидаемая красная подложка улетела под весь список (можно видеть сквозь полупрозрачный фон списка).
3. [Пробуем](http://jsfiddle.net/YGVkG/3/) увеличивать z-index у самого li, и все по новой.

Перестаю понимать, как работает z-index, и сомневаться, понимал ли вообще когда-нибудь :).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело? Куда копать? Может какая особенность у псевдоэлементов есть упущеная? Может у кого статейка на уме есть на эту тему?

**UPD:** проблему, очевидно, можно решить проставив z-index родителям, но тем самым мы пораждаем код который весь пронизан z-index`ами. Получается сильная зависимость от контекста и т.д. В крупном проекте не хотелось бы с таким столкнуться :). Хочется найти способ элегантного добавления такой подложки, не выходя за рамки элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cypher**, если Вы добавляете псевдоэлемент к `<li>` то он добавится внутрь `<li>`. Поэтому изменяя `z-index` `<li>` Вы ничего не получите.

Вам нужен дополнительный блок внутри

c бОльшим `z-index`

P.S. А Вам точно псевдоэлемент нужен? Может быть можно сделать с помощью `box-shadow`?

Comment: Думаю, что осознал. Спасибо. Для большей наглядности пример без псевдо-элементов: http://jsfiddle.net/YGVkG/4/ . Все проблмы с div`ом аналогичны.

Comment: Вообще, вижу, конечно, много способо: тени, как вы говорите, бордюры, псевдо-элементы перед и после. Они вполне могут решить часть задач. Дополнительная обертка, безусловно, тоже. Свою задачу так и решил. А вот универсального подхода для создания подложки не трогая HTML так и не нашел  :(. А она в последнее время что-то участилась.

Comment: Здесь, как часто бывает, нет универсального решения. Все зависит от задачи.

Кстати посмотрел что вы выложили на jsfiddle. Я другое имел ввиду:
http://jsfiddle.net/YGVkG/10/

Answer (score 1):

Можно без дополнительной разметки. Псевдоэлемент должен быть ниже фона, т.е. z-index должен быть -1. Но чтобы псевдоэлемент было видно, у самого элемента (в данном случае li) z-index должен быть 1 или больше (и разумеется позиционирование отличное от static, например, position: relative).